# Adding datetime to SQL database from formatted textbox fields

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I'm trying to add a datetime into a database table by grabbing values from textboxes that have various masks etc. I'm getting the following error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Textbox code:

```
<asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>    
                <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="calendarToolkit" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>   
                <asp:TextBox ID="startDateTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                <asp:CalendarExtender Format="yyyy-dd-MM"  ID="startDateExtender" TargetControlID="startDateTextbox" runat="server" /> 
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>    
                <asp:TextBox ID="startTimeTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="m1" runat="server" Mask="99:99" MaskType="Time" AcceptAMPM="false" 
                                    MessageValidatorTip="true" TargetControlID="startTimeTextbox"
                                    ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false">
                </asp:MaskedEditExtender>

                <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="mv1" runat="server" ControlExtender="m1" ControlToValidate="startTimeTextbox"
                                    Display="none" EmptyValueMessage="Time is required" InvalidValueMessage="Valid Start Time"
                                    IsValidEmpty="true" TooltipMessage="Input a time">
                </asp:MaskedEditValidator>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
```

c# code to add values into database:

```
string sqlQuery =
                "insert into dbo.Event_Info(event_name, description, location, date_end,date_start,image_url) values(@name, @desc, @location,@startDate,@endDate,@imageURL)";

SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("server=(local)\\SGSQL;database=STEvent;Trusted_Connection=yes");
            dbConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, dbConnection);

SqlParameter startParam = new SqlParameter("@startDate",SqlDbType.DateTime);
            startParam.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(startDateTextbox.Text +" " + startTimeTextbox.Text);

            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(startParam);
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            dbConnection.Close();
```

Note: Only added a subset of the code as showing all the other parameters seemed long and redundant.

Comment: What was the imput in the two textboxes?

Comment: @Derek 2012-01-12 and 11:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date format "yyyy-dd-MM" is invalid. You can lookup the "Convert" function in SQL Server documentation for valid formats.

"yyyy-MM-dd" is a good solution

Comment: Thank you, that worked and it's very simple. I'll accept your answer when I'm allowed to!

Answer (score 3):

Try to parse your `String` to `DateTime`.

```
// String to DateTime
 String MyString;
 MyString = "1999-09-01 21:34 PM";
 //MyString = "1999-09-01 21:34 p.m.";  //Depends on your regional settings

 DateTime MyDateTime;
 MyDateTime = new DateTime();
 MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt",
                                  null)
```